# Uma ajuda com annotations com Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testes-de-unidade, annotation

Uma ajuda com annotations … Hoje meus testes estão assim :

```
@ConfigA
@ConfigB
@ConfigC
@ConfigD
public class MeuTesteA {}

@ConfigA
@ConfigB
@ConfigC
@ConfigD
public class MeuTesteB {}
```

Veja, eu tenho que repetir muitas annotations de configuração. Para resolver, eu criei uma classe abstrata, ficando desta forma :

```
@ConfigA
@ConfigB
@ConfigC
@ConfigD
public abstract class ConfigTeste {}
```

E os testes ficaram assim. Neste ponto, funciona perfeitamente!

```
public class MeuTesteA extends ConfigTeste {}
public class MeuTesteB extends ConfigTeste {}
```

Mas ainda assim acho que da pra melhorar mais. Eu queria algo do tipo :

```
@SuperConfig
public class MeuTesteA {}

@SuperConfig
public class MeuTesteA {}
```

Onde minha annotation customizada @SuperConfig carregaria todas as configurações acima.
Eu tentei criar a “@SuperConfig” desta forma :

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ConfigA
@ConfigB
@ConfigC
@ConfigD
public @interface SuperConfig { 

}
```

Mas não funcionou. Não carrega as configurações. Sabe onde está o erro ?

PS :
As confgurações são essas :

```
@ActiveProfiles("[UM_AMBIENTE_AQUI]")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(Application.class)
@IntegrationTest("{server.port:8000, server.address:localhost}")
```

Estou usando Spring Boot na **versão 1.3.7.RELEASE**

Vlw´s

Comment: Por que não está carregando as configurações? O que aparenta não funcionar?

Comment: Não sei ! Simplesmente não carrega as configurações citadas quando uso minha anotação customizada (O proposito é para não repetir código).

Comment: Eu não entendi direito, mas acho que seria possivel parametrizar uma anotação Config com os demais campos por exemplo, a, b,c,d. Assim vc adicionaria só uma anotação

Comment: Opa Weslley Barbosa blz, então não são campos mas sim  configurações/anotações diferentes diferentes (as que coloquei no final da pergunta) . Eu queria agrupar todas numa só anotação customizada ao invés de estender uma classe como citei acima.
Já fez algo do tipo ?

Answer (score -1):

Acho que pode usar o
`@Import({ConfigTeste.class})`
, ele importa como se fosse uma @Bean com todas propriedades, annotations e afins

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).